# Permutations - combinations

Tags: combinatorics

Task is: ,,How many arrangements of the word TRIGONAL can be made if only two vowels and three consonants are used?"
The solution is quite clear: 3600 = 3C2 * 5C3 * 5!.
But, why I do not get the same result, if the method of permutations is used instead:
5*4*3*3*2 = 360 (I choose 3 out of five consonants and 2 out of three vowels)?
If I operate with numbers, I can get the same result using either methods (permutationa, combinations) - for exemple, how many three digit numbers can be formed, if we are to choose them from the set of these numbers: 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9. The solutions is: 6*5*4 = 120, or 6C3 * 3! = 120. Why this is not applicable to the situations such as aforementioned?

Answer (score 0):

The first method you proposed gives you the correct answer. The second method works as well.

There are $5$ ways to choose the first consonant that appears, $4$ ways to choose the second, and $3$ ways to choose the third. There are $3$ ways to choose the first vowel that appears, and $2$ ways to choose the other one.

Thus, there are $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 360$ ways to determine the ordered $3$- and $2$-tuples of consonants and vowels that are used in the rearrangement.

However, this counting would undercount. For example, TRIGO is considered the same as TRGIO or ITORG. What remains to be chosen are the places for the vowels.

There are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to choose which places the vowels take. THus, our final answer is $$5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot \binom{5}{2} = 360 \cdot 10 = 3600$$

This agrees with the answer you got using the other method.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But, if this is the solution, we can think of the situation - yes, I have the "firm" position of I and O in ITORG, but it is the same in ITOGR; similarly, in the varying 3-tuple, the same is 123579 and 123597. On the other hand, these different results are not contained in the main solution? I mean, should not it be imanent part of 5*4*3*3*2 all the situations that are part of the next/other method?

Comment: When we counted the $360$ ways, we counted the ways that fixed both the *order* of the consonants (e.g. T comes before R comes before G) and the *order* of the vowels (e.g. I comes before O).
$$\text{ }$$
The $\binom{5}{2}$ term in the final product fixes the "firm" position of the vowels, as you call it. However, ITOGR is different from ITORG because the *order* of the consonants is different. We differentiated between those two arrangements in the first $360$-count.